# Generate a random number from normal distribution in J

Tags: j

In J programming: I know how to get a linear random number.

```
? 5#10
1 3 3 4 7
```

But how to get a random number from normal distribution, e.g. N(0,1)? Thanks!

Comment: Note that a faster and leaner form exists for your example above: `5 ?@$ 10`. `?@$` is backed by [special code](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/special.htm) to provide improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [normalrand](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/stats/base/random#normalrand) in the stats package:

```
   load 'stats'
   normalrand 5
_0.514477 1.23645 _0.353373 _0.522193 1.23505
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very helpful! Do you know how to look into this stats package? I guess it may have other useful functions that I need.

Comment: There are a few other subpackages linked here: http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/stats/base; I am also just getting started, and mostly what I do is google with `site:jsoftware.com` and hope that I use the right word for something. Installing all the addons helps, and then you can grep your filesystem too!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

See also the [stats/distribs addon](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/stats/distribs)

```
   load 'stats/distrib'
   rnorm 4
_0.486091 _0.339021 1.50653 0.19308
   10 2 rnorm 4    NB. from distribution N(10,2)
10.0588 11.0472 13.6208 8.78888
```

Comment: What's the difference between this one and the one in my answer? Would one prefer one or the other?

Comment: For casual use, not much. However for generating large numbers of random numbers the version in `stats/distrib` is 3 times leaner and a bit faster. The addon also contains robust versions of the related verbs `qnorm` and `pnorm`. See the addon description in the link for more info.